# merging two data tables in a third table in c#

Tags: c#

I have two data tables containing one common column.I want to create a join between the two tables and get the data in a third table.

eg data table 1: column employeeid,name,number

data table 2: column employeeid

i want to remove all the employee id's that are in the second table from the first table and display the rest of the values.

Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could likely be modified to suit your needs:

```
var emps1 = dt1.Rows.Select( r => r[ "employeeid" ] ).Cast<int>();
var emps2 = dt2.Rows.Select( r => r[ "employeeid" ] ).Cast<int>();
var removeEmps = emps1.Intersect( emps2 );
foreach( int empId in removeEmps )
    // remove appropriate row from dt1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question,it seems like you just want to do a simple join.  You want all the rows in the first table but you want to add the additional columns that match from the second table.

In SQL that would be:

Select * from table1 T1
join table2 T2 on T1.employeeid = T2.employeeid

You can do anything with the result set including inserting it into a 3rd table.

Is that all you need to do?